# Failed to convert the downloaded code coverage tool to XML

Tags: c#, sonarqube, code-coverage

I have code coverage enabled on TFS 2013. I work with MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner 1.0.1. When I run the End phase of the Analysis. I get the following error messages:

```
    11:36:00.269  Failed to convert the downloaded code coverage tool to XML. No code coverage information will be uploaded to SonarQube.<br/>
     Check that the downloaded code coverage file (C:\Builds\39\[product name]\System_Main_Release_Code_Analysis\.sonarqube\out\VSCodeCoverageReport.coverage) is valid by opening it in Visual Studio. If it is not, check that the internet security settings on the build machine allow files to be downloaded from the Team Foundation Server machine.
     Post-processing failed. Exit code: 1
An error occurred while copying diagnostic activity logs to the drop location. Details: Forbidden
```

On the build server there is no VSCodeCoverageReport.coverage file - at least not at the indicated location and with that name. However, when I click on (Coverage Results) in the TFS Build summary, a coverage file is downloaded that opens up in Visual Studio in the Code Coverage Results Window.

What could be the issue?

Comment: Can you try to access the URL to the code coverage report on the TFS 2013 server that should be displayed just above in the logs? `Downloading coverage file from {0} to {1}`. Note that this download might silently fail, because if a non-success status code is returned, then nothing gets logged: https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-msbuild-runner/blob/1.0.1/SonarQube.TeamBuild.Integration/CoverageReportDownloader.cs#L55

Comment: I've created this ticket to not silently fail - but it won't solve the root cause of your issue which is still unknown: https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARMSBRU-152

Comment: @Dinesh: There is no line `Downloading coverage file from {0} to {1}` anywhere in the log files. I captured the URL used to download the coverage file. But I don't know if that would help you.
`http://[TFS-Servername]:8080/tfs/[company_product_name]/[product_name]/_api/_build/ItemContent?buildUri=vstfs%3A%2F%2F%2FBuild%2FBuild%2F19091&path=%2FBuildCoverage%2FSystem_Main_Release_Code_Analysis_20151014.1.Debug.Mixed%20Platforms.20703.coverage`

Comment: Could you add the few log lines before that error occurs in the question?

Comment: Here are some lines right before the error:
`MSBuild Log File
00:00
Run optional script after MSBuild
00:00
Run optional script before Test Runner

02:07
Run VS Test Runner

00:07
Run optional script after Test Runner`

Comment: looks like I won't be able to help you much :| I'd suggest to use a network traffic scanner (such as Wireshark) to see what HTTP calls are being made, compare the URL the MSBuild SonarQube Runner tries to download with the one you get through the TFS Build Summary - see if they match, and look at the HTTP response code the MSBuild SonarQube Runner is getting back. FYI https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARMSBRU-152 is now fixed and in version 1.0.2 it should become easier to investigate this issue.

Comment: @Dinesh: I see that 1.0.2 of the Sonar.Msbuild.Runner was released yesterday (https://jira.sonarsource.com/projects/SONARMSBRU?selectedItem=com.atlassian.jira.jira-projects-plugin:release-page&status=all) but the download link on SonarSource still points to 1.0.1 (http://www.sonarqube.org/downloads/). Will you make 1.0.2 available soon?

Comment: We've released an RC1 of the new 1.0.2 version, for which the vote is currently open on https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sonarqube/H8AQch3wACo - feel free to test & vote. If no issue is found, that release will become visible some time next week.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is **solved**.
The proxy settings on the build agent had changed. This resulted in http requests to the TFS server or any local addresses to fail.
It was particularly challanging to figure out, because the Agent build log that tells you all the details of a build is the file that could not be transferred to the drop location. 
So I used **ProcMon** from Sysinternals with File monitor enabled during a build. A comparison between a successful build in the past and a current failed build showed me which file was missing (**the agent log file**). A search in ProcMon for this file revealed where that file was located on the build agent. The Agent Log file contained the `Downloading coverage file from {0} to {1}` line Dinesh was looking for in his attempt to help me. That http address pasted into a browser showed an "Access denied" message. 
From there it was a logical step to analyse the Proxy settings. What finally solved it was to check "**Bypass proxy server for local addresses**" in the Local Area Network (LAN) Settings"